# Item ageing calculation in sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list, calculated-column

Need help to formulate a column to calculate the line item ageing based on Request Status.

If the request status moves to completed, it should stop/freeze the result.
If the request is in any other state, it should keep in calculating the number of days

Comment: So, If [Status]="Completed", you would need the [Calculated] column to show the number of days from the timestamp when the status was set to "Completed", right? A calculated column's value is refreshed/calculated when an item is created or modified. So, if item remains static calculated column value will retain its previous value.

Answer (score 0):

Calculated column value is fixed on calculation and does not update automatically, as Matiur Rahman said in the [comment](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/290517/item-ageing-calculation-in-sharepoint-list#comment308369_290517).

You can either update the item using a [scheduled flow](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/run-scheduled-tasks)/workflow (trigger daily), so that the calculated column will update with it.

And the sample formula you can use:

```
DATEDIF(Today(),[Created],"d")
```

Or you can use the flow/workflow to [update the column](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/How-can-I-update-only-1-property-in-a-SharePoint-List/td-p/82047) directly (without using formula).